# Doing Actions Simultaneously Versus In A Queue

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, flask

Say, there are **40 different users of a mobile app calling the server**, which delivers some content created using **FFMPEG**.

It takes about **5 seconds to create the content for each user**.

I was just wondering if **FFMPEG would process, the commands simultaneously, or if it would be done in a queue**.

Basically would it take approximately **5** seconds for everyone, or would it take **5 seconds - 200 seconds** for each person, depending on their queue positioning.

Also, if it *would be done via queueing, how would it be possible to change the task to become simultaneous* because I don't want my users to wait for a long time.

Comment: I know I am a bit of noob with this server-side stuff, so if I forgot to say any info that you need, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how many worker processes you have.

Since you added the Heroku tag, I'm assuming you're using Heroku. On Heroku, one dyno is one such worker process.

[Routing is more or less random on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/3/routing_and_web_performance_on_heroku_a_faq), but provided you have a large number of users (40 is probably not enough though), you should be able to serve as many users as you have dynos simultaneously.